# Некоректно работает поток ost

Tags: c++

```
namespace Product
{
string Name_product;
vector <string> save_name_product;
double sum_product(0);
vector <double> save_sum_product;
int count_product(0);
vector <int> save_count_product;
}
using namespace Product;

int main()
{
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    // руссификация консоли.
    // Открываем и записываем в фаил.
    string name;
    cout << " Назовите фаил:" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    ofstream ist(name.c_str());
    if (!ist) cout << " Фаил не открыт";
    string oname;
    cout << " В какой фаил сохранить данные?" << endl;
    cin >> oname;
    ofstream ost(name.c_str());
    if (!ost) cout << " Фаил не открыт!";
    system("cls");

    while (cin >> Name_product >> count_product >> sum_product)
    {
        system("cls");
        // затирания консоли , набраных значений.

        save_name_product.push_back(Name_product); // имя продукта.
        save_count_product.push_back(count_product); // кол-во продукта.
        save_sum_product.push_back(sum_product); // сумма продукта.

        for (int i = 0; i < save_name_product.size(),
            i < save_count_product.size(), i < save_sum_product.size(); ++i)

            if(i == 0 || save_name_product[i-1]!=save_name_product[i])
                //если повторяется строка , не пишем.
        {
            cout << i << "." << save_name_product[i] << setw(6)
                << save_count_product[i] << "count." << setw(6) << "sum."
                << save_sum_product[i] << "___"
                << asctime(timeinfo); 
                // время / дата на консоль.

            // пишем даные базы в фаил.
            ost << i << "." << save_name_product[i] << setw(6)
                << save_count_product[i] << "count." << setw(6) << "sum."
                << save_sum_product[i] << "___"
                << asctime(timeinfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Запись в file производится некорректно , все набранные элементы повторяются несколько раз и смешиваются между собой.
Мне нужно выполнить это задание именно так.
Это на данный момент все мои знания языка.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь , изучаю с++ самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо вынести цикл `for` из цикла `while`.

Как я понимаю, цикл `while` должен сначала заполнить все элементы векторов. А после него уже цикл `for` должен вывести эти элементы в файл.

То есть циклы должны следовать друга за другом как, например,

```
while ( условие )
{
    //....
}

for ( параметры )
{
    // ....
}
```

а не быть вложенными друг в друга.
Имейте в виду, что условие в этом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < save_name_product.size(),
    i < save_count_product.size(), i < save_sum_product.size(); ++i)
```

не имеет большого смысла, так как оно полностью эквивалентно условию в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < save_sum_product.size(); ++i)
```

в виду того, что в первом цикле в условии используется оператор запятая, который возвращает значение лишь последнего операнда.

Comment: я добавил в тело while цикл for , чтобы пользователь видел что происходит на экране и отдельно в цикл for вывел результат и запись в файл , всё работает отлично. Спасибо за помощь!
А в цикле вместо запятых использовал ||

Comment: у меня возник такой вопрос , а можно ли после записи данных в файл открыть его на консоль для редактирования?

Comment: @its_space Консоль не позволяет редактировать данные. Вам следует считать данные в объекты некоторых типов, как, например, std::string, и в этих объектах их редактировать.

Comment: я тут создал структуру , которая читает информацию из файла , добавляя знаки пунктуации между числами , это видно в цикле for и сохраняет отредактированные данные в другой файл. Вопрос , как вывести на консоль прочитанную информацию прежде чем программа сохранит отредактированные данные в другой файл?

Comment: `struct Reading {
 int hour;
 double temperature;
 Reading(int h, double t) :hour(h), temperature(t) {}
};
 vector <Reading> temps;
 int hour;
 double temperature;
 while (ist >> hour >> temperature) {
  if (hour < 0 || 23 < hour) cout << "некорректное время";
  temps.push_back(Reading(hour, temperature));
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i) {
 ost << '(' << temps[i].hour << "," << temps[i].temperature << ")\n";
 }
}`